# Get every second URL from HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am struggling with scraping URL's from a website. The HTML code from the website I want to scrape is:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <span>

    <table class="search-result-ad-row" cellspacing="3" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="picture" rowspan="2"><a title="3.izbový byt v starom meste na ulici Kpt. Nálepku" href="inzerat/RE0005055-16-000281/3-izbovy-byt-v-starom-meste-na-ulici-kpt-nalepku"><img src="/data/189/RE0005055/ads/195/RE0005055-16-000281/img/thum/37587134.jpeg" alt=""/></a>
            </td>
            <td class="title" colspan="2"><a title="3.izbový byt v starom meste na ulici Kpt. Nálepku" href="inzerat/RE0005055-16-000281/3-izbovy-byt-v-starom-meste-na-ulici-kpt-nalepku"><h2 style="font-size: inherit;">3.izbový byt v starom meste na ulici Kpt. Nálepku</h2></a>
                <span></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

I want to get the `href` by using this python code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.reality.sk/")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br["tabs:scrn243:scrn115:errorTooltip.cityName:cityName"]="poprad"
br.submit()

def hello():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        link2 = link.get('href')
        if "inzerat/" in link2:
            print 'http://www.reality.sk/' + link.get('href')
```

But the problem is I get 2 results for each URL (because there are 2 `href` attributes). I have tried to scrape using the `table` tag, the `td` tag with a `class` attribute (either "picture" or "title") or even using `rowspan` (=2). But I am not getting the desired result. I don't know how to make code work.

Comment: Is there some edge case or other specific reason why you couldn't just use modulus to `continue` the loop every *other* iteration?

Comment: It seems you are getting the same link twice. Can't you just filter out for dupes with a simple `set` operation? (or get links every other iteration with something like `soup.findAll('a')[::2]`, as @Tersosauros suggested?)

Comment: @Tersosauros ... To be honest I am not very experienced in programming and did not think about every other iteration loop.But I try what  Gustavo Bezerra wrote - soup.findAll('a')[::2] and it work, so must THANK bouth of you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you had issues with looking up by the `class` selector. Also you can chain the tags returned by find - please take a look if this solution helps (I'm not 100% sure if that's what you want to achieve):

```
soup.find_all('table', class_='search-result-ad-row')
for ad_table in soup.find_all('table', class_='search-result-ad-row'):
    print ad_table.find(class_='picture').find('a').attrs['href']
```